# Issue in hobbies, as unable to get selected values using PHP

Tags: php

I have provided pre tag at the top so that i can see what values are going when i click on ragister button, all values are going correct except hobbies as its giving "on" why this so, please let know and I am new to php please explain me in detail as much as you can.

```
<?php

$error_array = array();
$fname = $lname = $email = $dob = $Mchecked = $Fchecked = $hobbies ="";

if(isset($_POST["sbt_save"]))
{   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";
    if($_POST['fname']=="")
    {           
        $err ="Please Enter your first name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = test_input($_POST['fname']);
    }

    if($_POST['lname']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your last name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    }

    if($_POST['email']=="")
    {       
        $err ="Please Enter your email"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if($_POST['dob']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your date of birth"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
    }

    if(!isset($_POST["gender"]))
    {
        $err ="Please select gender"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        if ($gender == "Male")
        {
            $Mchecked = "checked";
        }
        else if ($gender == "Female")
        {
            $Fchecked = "checked";
        }
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['hobbies']))
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your hobbies"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $hobbies = test_input($_POST['hobbies']);
    }

}


function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ragistration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ragistration_form.css">
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
$(document).ready(function(event)
{       

    $(".sbt_button").click(function(event)
    {        
        var error_arr = [];             
        var email_value = $("#email").val();                    
        var position_of_at  = email_value.indexOf('@');         
        var position_of_dot = email_value.lastIndexOf('.');



        if($("#fname").val() == null || $("#fname").val() == "")
        {
             var err = "First Name";
             error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#lname").val() == null || $("#lname").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Last Name ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }
        if(position_of_at == -1 || position_of_dot == -1 || (position_of_at + 2) >= position_of_dot )
        {
            var err = "Email ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#dob").val() == null || $("#dob").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Date of Birth ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='radio']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Gender ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Hobbies ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }


        if(error_arr.length !=0)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            alert(error_arr);   
        }           
    });
});
*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form" name="myForm" action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<p class="heading">Ragistration Form</p>
</tr>

<?php
if($error_array !="")
{   
    foreach($error_array as $value)
    {
        echo "<tr><td> ". $value. "</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>

<tr>
<td class="field_Name">First Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="inputfield_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">Last Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="inputfield_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">Email :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputfield_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">Date of Birth :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"  class="inputfield_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">Gender :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"class="inputfield_Name" <?php echo $Mchecked;?>/>Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php echo $Fchecked;?> />Female</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">About Yourself :</td>
<td><textarea name="abt" class="inputfield_Name"$></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field_Name">Hobbies :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox" id="hobbies"  class="inputfield_Name" />Cricket
    <input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox" />Singing
    <input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox" />Travling</td>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
    <input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox"  class="inputfield_Name"/>Writing
    <input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox" />Teaching
    <input name="hobbies"  type="checkbox" />Driving
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Ragister" name="sbt_save"  class="sbt_button"/></td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add value attributes to the checkbox elements:

```
 <tr>
<td class="field_Name">Hobbies :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
<td><input name="hobbies" value="cricket" type="checkbox" id="hobbies"  class="inputfield_Name" />Cricket
    <input name="hobbies" value="singing" type="checkbox" />Singing
    <input name="hobbies"  value="travelling" type="checkbox" />Travling</td>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
    <input name="hobbies"  value="writing" type="checkbox"  class="inputfield_Name"/>Writing
    <input name="hobbies"  value="teaching" type="checkbox" />Teaching
    <input name="hobbies"  value="driving" type="checkbox" />Driving
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanx, @Jamkelvl... One more thing is there any other simple way to do validation in "gender" as i'm unable to understand this....in my code

Comment: This link shows a form similar to yours and discusses validation. Maybe that will help. [PHP Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)

Comment: Are you trying to validate if the gender radio button has been checked?  If so it looks like you're trying to push a value from jQuery into a PHP array which is not possible.  PHP is a server-side language and jQuery is client-side.  You'll need to do your validation with just jQuery or just PHP or both if you want to cover users who do not have javascript enabled.

Comment: another issue with this code is whenever i just put any one value and click on ragister it gets submitted, so how can i prevent that???

Comment: You need to use an array-style name for hobbies `name="hobbies[]"`. Otherwise you'll just get the last hobby they checked, not all of them.

Comment: @Shanky Use the `required` attribute on all the required inputs. Then it won't allow the form to be submitted until they've entered all of them.